# App crashes while navigating with in the ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am working on creating a gallery like view with view pager and fragments using this  implementation  http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging .

In my code I will fetch NUM_PAGES (integer) in viewpager from a web server for particular logged in user.

What I am doing:

My pages are populated with information when the user logs in to the app, which does many checks to populate one page, So I created all the views when onCreate() is called, and reusing them each time a fragment requires them.

when I launch my app with multiple pages in viewpager, navigating through page 1 through page 5, The app works fine, when I try to revisit the previous page, the app crashes with the "java.lang.IllegalStateException".

I am new to fragments and viewpager, Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Kiran

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3435)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3306)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3251)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3227)
    at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
```

My Code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){

    //my code here

    //prepare views to be used with viewpager
    setupViews();

    //setup viewpager stuff
    mAdapter = new ViewsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //other initializations here
}

public static class ViewsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{


    public ViewsAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = new VehicleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putInt(VehicleFragment.VEHICLE_INDEX, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return NUM_PAGES;// this value will be fetched at runtime from a server.
    }

}

public class VehicleFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String VEHICLE_INDEX = "VEHICLE_INDEX";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int position = args.getInt(VEHICLE_INDEX); 
        Log.i("VehicleHome", "retrieving position : "+position+" in viewsList, where viewsList size = "+viewsList.size());
        return viewsList.get(position);
    }
}

private void setupViews() {

//prepare Views here, the views are created at runtime and added to viewsList (ArrayList) 
//for reuse with fragments. So that each time a new instance of fragment is created we won't endup 
//inflating layout file and initializing the view again and again..

//views logic 

viewsList.add(view);

}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you clean this question, remove code that is  redundant for understanding the question, and display what's relevant from the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shouldn't create a new fragment every time a page is requested. Instead create them all at once and then just return the correct one:

```
public static class ViewsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

    public ViewsAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
            Fragment fragment = new VehicleFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            args.putInt(VehicleFragment.VEHICLE_INDEX, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragments.add(fragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // in case dynamic amount of fragments is needed, you can create
        // new ones here if necessary (checking e.g. if position > fragments.size()-1)
        fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

}
```

Comment: hi Nieminen, Tried with what you said, still the problem persists. I think the problem is with the way Iam tying view to a fragment. coz once I have returned a view for the first time underlying viewpager impl could be trying to add the view back to fragment again for the subsequent calls...

Comment: Hmm. With another look, the `setupViews` looks somewhat suspicious. You can't reuse specific Views as far as I know, that might explain the `IllegalStateException`. Once the view has a parent, you can't use the same view in another place. What I'd do next is to remove the view optimisations that you have and just create the views separately for each fragment.

Comment: finally I could solve my problem, I've changed my implementation to use FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter and stopped reusing the views. Its now working fine(though I couldn't optimize my code).